# Cargo repeatedly builds rdkafka-sys

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, librdkafka

I have a Rust project which continually builds `rdkafka-sys` every time anything changes.

Normally, I would expect Cargo not to rebuild dependencies if they have not changed. For all other dependencies in the project, this is the observed behaviour.

However, if I make a change to any of my code, and trigger another Cargo build, Cargo first goes and builds the whole of `rdkafka-sys`, but none of the other dependencies, despite the fact that nothing in `rdkafka-sys` has changed.

Can anyone indicate as to why this might be happening? This is presumably not the expected behaviour?

Comment: I've had this problem while having a rust-analyzer based editor open on the same project while building. You could try setting `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` for your `cargo build`s to something that's definitely not used by something else in parallel.

Comment: That sounds familiar, I am using the Rust analyzer, but I don't understand the suggested solution. Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Its not really a solution yet, more an investigation approach: try running `env CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=alttarget cargo build` twice and see if that also rebuilds rdkafka. If it doesn't, you can be relatively sure that something (most likely rust analyzer - try exiting that for a while, too, maybe?) is messing with your `target/` dir. How to spin  a solution out of that... Always setting `CARGO_BUILD_TARGET` to something sure works, but it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

CTRL+SHIFT+P

> "settings.json" -> Open User Settings.json

Add:

```
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.extraArgs": [
        "--target-dir",
        "rust_analyzer_target"
  ],
```